# Leaderstats not working? or just not detecting the click?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a Simulator game on Roblox but I just can't seem to get the leader stats to work or it does work and my click event thing doesn't work, I am just following a tutorial for the scripting so I have no clue. This is my Remotes script where it says print("IS THIS WORKING") that was to see what was the problem. Basically that doesn't run or there's another problem that stops that from running, I think at least. I have other scripts and I will put some in that I think might be neccesary but if you need more feel free to ask me.

```
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remoteData = game:GetService("ServerStorage"):WaitForChild("RemoteData")

local cooldown = 1
print("IS THIS WORKING")

replicatedStorage.Remotes.Lift.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    
    
    if not remoteData:FindFirstChild(player.Name) then return "NoFolder" end
    
    
    local debounce = remoteData[player.Name].Debounce
    
    if not debounce then
        
        debounce.Value = true
        
        player.leaderstats.Stealth.Value = player.leaderstats.Stealth.Value + 25 *(player.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value + 1)
        wait(cooldown)
        
        debounce.Value = false
        
    end
```

Stats

```
local serverStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

    
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player
    
    local stealth = Instance.new("NumberValue")
    stealth.Name = "Stealth"
    stealth.Parent = leaderstats
    
    local rebirths = Instance.new("IntValue")
    rebirths.Name = "Rebirths"
    rebirths.Parent = leaderstats
    
    local Folder = Instance.new("Folder")
    Folder.Name = player.Name
    Folder.Parent = serverStorage.RemoteData

    local debounce = Instance.new("BoolValue")
    debounce.Name = "Debounce"
    debounce.Parent = Folder
    
    
    end)
```

ModuleScript

```
local module = {}

local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
function module.Lift()
    
    replicatedStorage.Remotes.Lift:FireServer()
    
end
return module
```

LocalScript

```
local module = require(script.Parent:WaitForChild("ModuleScript"))
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()

script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    module.Lift()
end)
```

For my Explorer Structure click
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YnyE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local remoteData = game:GetService("ServerStorage"):WaitForChild("RemoteData")
```

your problem is when it waits for a child it yields the script until RemoteData is found

later in the script, it checks if RemoteData is nil or not

```
 if not remoteData:FindFirstChild(player.Name) then return "NoFolder" end
```

two solutions:
first is to add a max wait for the yield so it will eventually stop if it can't find RemoteData (only useful is RemoteData is added after the script starts running)

second is the replace wait with FindFirstChild that will check immediately without waiting for it

the solution I recommend

```
local remoteData = game:GetService("ServerStorage"):FindFirstChild("RemoteData")
```

secondary solution if you have RemoteData added after the script starts and want to double-check

```
local remoteData = game:GetService("ServerStorage"):WaitForChild("RemoteData",20)
```

be sure to tell me is this works as I spent a while figuring it out